# How do I set the request server name using Spring's MockMvc framework?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, junit, mockmvc

I'm using Spring 4.3.8.RELEASE.  In my integration test, I'm using SPring's MockMvc framework, set up like so ...

```
@Autowired 
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;
...
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
...
    mockMvc.perform(get(contextPath + "/path") 
                    .contextPath(contextPath)
                    .principal(auth)
                    .param("param1", param1)
                    .param("param2", param2))
```

what I cannot figure out is how to set the server name of my request.  That is, when my controller is invoked that populates

```
final HttpServletRequest request
```

How do I set

```
request.getServerName()
```

from the MockMvc call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [RequestPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/RequestPostProcessor.html) we can setup `MockHttpServletRequest` and mock up data.

```
    mockMvc.perform(get(contextPath + "/path").contextPath(contextPath).principal(auth).param("param1", param1).param("param2", param2).with(new RequestPostProcessor() {
        public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
            request.setServerName("system");
            return request;
        }
    }));
```